# Subtracting dates in where clause

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I need to make a select with the past 60 days starting in the present day.
For example:

```
select * from product
where product.expire_date = ?1 - 60
```

?1 is a parameter with today's date.

I can't make it work, what am I doing wrong?

I use MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you'd like.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product
WHERE product.expire_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Note that `BETWEEN` is inclusive.

NB, if your `expire_date` is a `datetime` field and not a `date` field, you might have to modify it a bit (i.e. `CONCAT()` the appropriate time strings to the references on the RHS of the `BETWEEN`, or throw a `DATE()` around the LHS of the `BETWEEN` (but then you would no longer use an index on `expire_date`, assuming there was one.

Comment: The only thing that you did wrong was by swithing the dates.
The lower date must be on the beggining.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

For more help : WHERE date BETWEEN dateX AND date_sub(dateX, 60days). I think that what you want right ?